# Dimension 3 indecomposable modules of a group $G = \langle x \rangle \times \langle y \rangle$ of order $p^2$

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, representation-theory

Let $G = \langle x \rangle \times \langle y \rangle$ where $|x| = |y| = p$. We wish to show there are exactly two (up to isomorphism) 3-dimensional $kG$-modules with $(x-1)^2W = (y-1)^2W=0$.

I don't think it's overly difficult to show that two such module structures exist. Where I get stuck is showing that these are all the isomorphism classes. We have results on when a module is indecomposable and when a module is simple but I don't see a nice technique for gathering all the indecomposable so I presume there is an idea special to this case.

EDIT:
I forgot to mention that $k$ is an algebraically closed field of characteristic $p$. Also, to clarify I wish to establish why there are exactly two indecomposable $kG$-modules of dimension $3$ satisfying the condition above satisfying the above condition.

Comment: Also, I don't understand your comment about maximal submodules of $kG$. $kG$ has only one maximal submodule. What do you mean by $k\langle x\rangle$?

Comment: $k\langle x \rangle$ is the space spanned by the elements of $\langle x \rangle$ which would be isomorphic to $k\langle y \rangle$. What I should have said is that it has two obvious isomorphic maximal submodules unless I am misunderstanding.

Comment: In your edit: There are more than three indecomposable modules of dimension $3$ (at least if $p>2$). You still only want those with $(x-1)^2W = (y-1)^2W=0$?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: But the space spanned by $\langle x\rangle$ is not a submodule (it's not closed under multiplication by $y$).

Comment: Sorry, what I meant implicitly is that space $k\langle x \rangle \times 0$ which would be closed under multiplication by $y$. What I wrote down is incorrect. But wouldn't $kG$ still have non-ismorphic maximal submodules as the multiplication from $G$ on $k\langle x \rangle \times 0$ would differ from the multiplication from $G$ on $0 \times k\langle y \rangle$

Comment: I'm still not sure what you mean by $k\langle x\rangle\times0$. The only maximal submodule of $kG$ is the augmentation ideal (i.e., the set $\{\sum_{g\in G}\lambda_gg\mid \sum_{g\in G}\lambda_g=0\}$).

Comment: What I meant, though it seems this is incorrect, is the $k$ vector space with basis vectors the elements of $\langle x \rangle \times 0$ given a $kG$ module structure using the obvious multiplication.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an outline of a proof using elementary linear algebra. You could probably make it shorter by assuming some theory (about radicals, etc.)

First, it will be more convenient to think about the actions of the elements $u=x-1$ and $v=y-1$ of the group algebra, rather than directly about the action of $x$ and $y$. Since $x^p=y^p=1$ and $\operatorname{char}(k)=p$, we have $u^p=v^p=0$, but the condition required of the modules means that $u^2$ and $v^2$ act as zero. Also, the actions of $u$ and $v$ commute.

Let $M$ be an indecomposable module on which $u^s$ and $v^2$ act as zero. First consider the action of $u$ on $M$. Since $u^2$ acts as zero, $Mu$ is in the kernel of the action of $u$. Choose a basis of $M$ as follows: first choose a basis of $Mu$, extend to a basis of $\{m\in M\mid mu=0\}$, and then extend to a basis of $M$ by including one element $b$ such that $bu=c$ for each basis element $c$ of $Mu$.

This gives a basis of $M$ such that for each basis element $b$, either $bu=0$ or $bu$ is another basis element, with at most one $b$ such that $bu=c$ for each basis element $c$. [For algebraically closed $k$, you could get this by considering the Jordan normal form of the action of $u$.]

Since $\dim(M)=3$, there are not many possibilities for the number of $b$ with $bu=0$. There are either $3$ or $2$, in which case $M$ is the direct sum of $3$ or $2$ nonzero $u$-stable subspaces. But if there are three, then $Mu=0$ and so every subspace is $u$-stable, and the same considerations applied to $v$ show that $M$ is the direct sum of $3$ or $2$ nonzero submodules, and so is not indecomposable.

So $M$ has a basis $\{s,t,tu\}$ where $su=tu^2=0$, and $M=S\oplus T$ is the direct sum of two $u$-stable subspaces, where $S=\langle s\rangle$ and $T=\langle t,tu\rangle$.

Now consider the action of $v$.

If both $S$ and $T$ are $v$-stable, then $M$ is not indecomposable.

If $Sv\not\leq S$, then a simple calculation shows that, up to multiplying $s$ by a nonzero scalar, we can assume that $sv=tu$ and $tv=0$. So $M$ is the module with basis $\{s,t,sv=tu\}$ (with all basis elements killed by $u$ and by $v$ except that $sv\neq0\neq tu$).

If $Sv\leq S$ but $Tv\not\leq T$, then a simple calculation shows that, up to replacing $s$ with a linear combination of $s$ and $tu$, we can assume that $tv=s$. So $M$ is the module with basis $\{t,tu,tv\}$ (with all basis elements killed by $u$ and by $v$ except that $tu\neq0\neq tv$).